# Python Bloomberg API ( 'DLL load failed' )

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi

My Python version is 2.7.3 and OS is Windows 7.

I want to use the Bloomberg API libraries. Specifically, 'importing error blpapi' is my most problem.

At [this site](http://www.bloomberglabs.com/api/libraries/),
I've tried to run both Supported Release(v3.5.5) and Experimental Release(v3.5.3).
But both are not work.

Writing `import blpapi` in IDLE, 
I keep getting an following error message:

> **Traceback (most recent call last):**
>
> File `<pyshell#0>`, line 1, in `<module>`
>
> ```
> import blpapi
> ```
>
> File `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\blpapi\__init__.py`, line 5, in `<module>`
>
> ```
> from .internals import CorrelationId
> ```
>
> File `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\blpapi\internals.py`, line 50, in `<module>`
>
> ```
> _internals = swig_import_helper()
> ```
>
> File `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\blpapi\internals.py`, line 46, in `swig_import_helper`
>
> ```
> _mod = imp.load_module('_internals', fp, pathname, description)
> ```
>
> **ImportError:** dll load failed specified module could not found

How can I solve this problem?
(I hope to import 'blpapi')

Comment: have u installed v3.5.5 (zip) from bloomberg website?

Comment: Yes, I did. And bloomberg library was installed in my site-packages   folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With reference to this: [Python 2.7 with Bloomberg API import blpapi failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24317469/python-2-7-with-bloomberg-api-import-blpapi-failure)

> The ImportError is the result of Bloomberg not being able to find the
>   "blpapi3_32.dll" DLL file. This DLL file can be located under the \bin
>   or \lib folder of Bloomberg's C/C++ library, which is at the same
>   location where you got your Python executable. So go download that
>   library (v3.7.5.1 as of this writing), and have your system's "Path"
>   environment variable include that location. This should resolve the
>   issue.
>
> PS you can access the PATH variable via Start > right-clicking
>   "Computer" > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Advanced (tab) >
>   Environment Variables > look for the "Path" variable under "System
>   variables". Edit this variable to include the location of the DLL
>   file, e.g. if the original Path variable is
>   "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4", then new Path variable should
>   be
>   "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\blp\API\blpapi_cpp_3.7.5.1\bin"

Comment: Thank you. I've finished download and installation, but i can't find 'blpapi3_32.dll' file.

Comment: No, just created a 'blpapi-3.5.5' folder and it include 2 subfolders('blpapi','examples') there's no blpapi3_32.dll. Specific contain files are same as 'v3.5.5 (zip)' at above Bloombger website.

Comment: Just to add: this works also for the latest blpapi v3.9 version.

Comment: Was getting the same issue on a new machine deployment and couldn't get the steps above to work - only to realise the Bloomberg terminal version hadn't been updated for a few years, a Bloomberg update fixed it.