# Import error for blpapi module

Tags: python, python-3.6, bloomberg, blpapi

This is my first post. I run the following: 
Win 10
Anaconda with Python 3.6.5
Bloomberg Anywhere

I am trying to use the `blpapi` (bloomberg professional API) for Python. Downloaded the Desktop API package (with C++ libraries), downloaded `blpapi-3.9.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl` installer file and ran it succesfully. Finally I added the `C:\..\C++API\v3.11.6.1\bin` to my path in both user and environment variables (from earlier query here on stackoverflow):
[Python 2.7 with Bloomberg API import blpapi failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24317469/python-2-7-with-bloomberg-api-import-blpapi-failure)

My error message when running `import blpapi`:

```
>---------------------------------------------------------------------------
>ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
>~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\blpapi\internals.py in swig_import_helper()
>     38         try:
>---> 39             return importlib.import_module(mname)
>     40         except ImportError:
>
>~\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
>    125             level += 1
>--> 126     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>    127 >>
>
>~\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)
>
>~\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)
>
>~\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, >import_)
>
>~\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _load_unlocked(spec)
>
>~\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in module_from_spec(spec)
>
>~\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap_external.py in create_module(self, spec)
>
>~\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, >**kwds)
>
>ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
>During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
>ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
>~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\blpapi\__init__.py in <module>()
>      3 try:
>----> 4     from .internals import CorrelationId
>      5 except ImportError as error:
>
>~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\blpapi\internals.py in <module>()
>     41             return importlib.import_module('_internals')
>---> 42     _internals = swig_import_helper()
>     43     del swig_import_helper
>
>~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\blpapi\internals.py in swig_import_helper()
>     40         except ImportError:
>---> 41             return importlib.import_module('_internals')
>     42     _internals = swig_import_helper()
>
>~\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
>    125             level += 1
>--> 126     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>    127 
>
>ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_internals'
>
>During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
>ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
><ipython-input-1-ee203a799ece> in <module>()
>----> 1 import blpapi
>
>~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\blpapi\__init__.py in <module>()
>     27 
>     28 """ % (str(error), env)
>---> 29     raise ImportError(msg)
>     30 
>     31 from .abstractsession import AbstractSession
>
>ImportError: No module named '_internals'
>
>Could not open the C++ SDK library.
>
>Download and install the latest C++ SDK from:
>
>    http://www.bloomberg.com/professional/api-library
>
>If the C++ SDK is already installed, please ensure that the path to the library
>was added to PATH before entering the interpreter.
```

Does someone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Did you try downloading and installing the latest C++ SDK?

Comment: Thanks - the Bloomberg support told me that their Desktop API package would be all I needed, so no. But I'm happy to try! Would that be the entire Visual Studio package I should download and install?

Comment: I was going to say the link they gave you in the error:
http://www.bloomberg.com/professional/api-library

Comment: Ah yes, I have. The SDK they link to is already part of the 'Desktop API package' which I've downloaded. I'm not sure if there is another way to change my 'path'..

Comment: Hmm, sorry that's all I've got. I don't actually know/use this software, I'm just being Captain obvious

Comment: Alright, thanks nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

Having exactly the same issue.
Comparability issues.

The **solution** for me was to roll back the version of python to **3.7.7 64-bit**

```
from: 3.8.3 32-bit
to: 3.7.7 64-bit
```

The BLPAPI works if the versions are compatible otherwise they fail.

Bloomberg dll files:

```
blpapi3_32.dll (version 3.14.3.1)
blpapi3_64.dll (version 3.14.3.1)
```

This solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I installed Microsoft Build Tools 2017 and added the BLPAPI_ROOT path as described in the linked question in my original post.